# How to access MethodChannel from a Java's Service class?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I am new to writing native Android Java code.

I'm trying to invoke a Dart method using Flutter's `MethodChannel` from another Java class that extends a `Service` and doesn't have the `configureFlutterEngine`.

How would I achieve this?